# aws elastic beanstalk creates snapshot of mysql db

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I think my Elastic Beanstalk app is creating snapshots of my MySQL database.
How can I stop it from doing so ?

Best regards

Comment: Which database you are using? As a part of your Beanstalk environment or outside?

Comment: MySQL rds free tier, outside.